# Compound to replace o-ring

Tags: seals

I have an aluminum cooling plate with a water path inside. The structure is simple- one part with a snake-like cut and a flat cover. To seal this thing I have designed a cut for an o-ring. The problem: design is tied to electronic parts and therefore changes from time to time, so i can't order o-ring of a certain length.

I can see certain IP67 connectors that have seals that are not o-rings, but rather look like a compound.

[image]

Is there a compound that would form a seal, similar to what oring does - but without me worrying about length and exact profile?

Comment: Why post this again? The last one was closed due to lack of detail and you have not improved it.

Comment: @SolarMike Then help me, what details am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish your objective. The messier method would be to use a suitable RTV silicone compound, frequently found in squeeze tubes. The nozzle of the tube can be cut to provide an appropriate diameter for your purpose. Typical RTV silicone compounds require outgassing in order to properly cure, which for some products creates a vinegar-like odor. Newer versions also outgas but do not smell the same. If provision is not made for this release of gas, curing time is extended substantially.

One could also use a two-part silicone molding material, available in liquid A/B components as well as in a putty A/B form. Both types cure via chemical reaction and usually involve relatively short curing times, especially compared to RTV types. The putty type can be manipulated by hand to create "ropes" to fit your application.

If the cut is created via machining, one can duplicate that bit in a piece of suitable stock, apply the choice of silicone, allow it to cure and remove the now-ready-to-install "O-ring" in the part.